# create PHP Variables from data in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `global_settings` with 2 columns `(field, value)`

i need a way to make each row a variable

so for example:

is `field = title` and `value = hello` i would need:

```
$title = 'hello';
```

I have tried doing this:

```
$global_sql="SELECT * from global_settings ";
$global_rs=mysql_query($global_sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($global_result=mysql_fetch_array($global_rs))
{
    $global_sql2="SELECT * from global_settings where field =  '".$global_result["field"]."' ";
    $global_rs2=mysql_query($global_sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $global_result2=mysql_fetch_array($global_rs2);

    $global_result2["field"] = $global_result2["value"];
}
```

but that didn't work - any ideas?

Comment: This is easy to do as an array - `$global_settings[$field] = $value`. Do you really need to make them specific variables?

Comment: @andrewsi do i put this outside the while loop or inside

Comment: i need to be able to echo the variables- for example a website title and email address but more may be added by the user

Comment: In your code, you could use `$config[$global_result2["field"]] = $global_result2["value"];` - just replace the last line of your loop with that. You should also initialise the value of `$config` before the loop, too.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. Use [mysqli](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Why doing a second query? You already have both the fields and the values.

Comment: how do i echo just one row?

Comment: Do you mean the first, or one that you can determine with the field's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest you do not auto-create variables from your DB. You'll be littering your script's namespace with potentially useless variables, and probably overwriting other variables you DID want to keep separate. Do it as you are - store the settings in an array.

Plus, unless I'm totally misreading your code, there's absolutely no reason for the sub-query. A simple:

```
$settings = array();
$sql = "SELECT field, value FROM settings"
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $settings[$row['field']] = $row['value'];
}
```

is all you need to grab all of the settings.

Comment: oops i wrote my answer while you wrote yours, sorry :)

Comment: how do i echo just one row?

Comment: `echo $settings['foo']`?

Answer (score 0):

This line will not create a variable named after the value for `field`.

```
$global_result2["field"] = $global_result2["value"];
```

You can create an array variable, for example:

```
$array_of_results[ $global_result2["field"] ] = $global_result2["value"];
```

This way you will have the following array:

```
[ 'field' => 'value' ]
```